# what is an automation test

Tags: testing, automation

Could someone explain what an automation test is and why I would use it. I read from the wiki page that a tester would create a automation script? What kind of scripting language can be used to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automation tests are carried out to check the behavior of an application against expected behavior. Normally used in regression testing where you validate that a newer version of the application doesn't hinder any of the previous version's features. These might also be carried along with manual testing.

Coming to the scripting language part, this might help you:- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/best-language-or-tool-for-automating-tedious-manual-tasks

Comment: @RDoolabh Let's leave that to the user to decide which language will be helpful based on his domain.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, If you are doing regression test or testing same piece of code over and over you can automate that manual process. That's called automation testing.

You can use several different scripting languages to achieve this and it's depends on which tool you are using. Some popular automation tools are Selenium, QTP, Loadrunner, Jmeter, SOAP UI etc.

Comment: Be careful with your tool items here.  The ones you note operate at different layers of the OSI model.  Some are at the GUI Layer, others at the application protocol layer.  Match your tool to the expected result you need to match and the layer which produces that output.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check your login with more than 1000 of users how much time you will spend to run this test case ?
In the same way you want to test you mobile API's before  it used by developer how will you test?
There are lots of thing for that you have to go for automation In small application, sites you can work as an tester after  that when those app's  sites will grow will large data than those product owner will move for automated test cases

Answer (score 0):

Automation testing refers to using software tools and scripts to perform testing tasks. It involves the use of existing automation frameworks or newly designed one and scripts to execute test cases, compare actual with expected results and generate test reports accordingly.
The primary goal of automation testing is to streamline the testing process, reduce manual effort, and improve the efficiency and accuracy of testing.

The choice of tool depends on factors such as the type of application being tested, the testing objectives, the programming language preference, and the budget.
Selenium, Appium, Robot, TestNG, Playwright, WebDriverIO, Cypress etc.